# Cannot delete files (.delete() Return false)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file

I'm trying to delete an image from a directory,  but when I use the method it returns false

```
public void deleteImage() {

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Angular/JPEG_20181010_282_9_320446411.jpg";

    //Result Path: /storage/emulated/0/Angular/JPEG_20181010_282_9_320446411.jpg

    File fdelete = new File(file_path); 
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
        if (fdelete.delete()) { //This return false
            Log.e("-->", "file Deleted :" + file_path );
        } else {
            Log.e("-->", "file not Deleted :" + file_path );
        }
    }
}
```

I have been collecting examples of other posts, but none of them work for me

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: sorry I don't know where to run it

Comment: I guess you mean the terminal built in the IDE, it say "adb" unknow command

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your logic and your method to :

```
public void deleteImage() {

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Angular/JPEG_20181010_282_9_320446411.jpg";

    //Result Path: /storage/emulated/0/Angular/JPEG_20181010_282_9_320446411.jpg

    File fdelete = new File(file_path); 
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
            fdelete.delete() // delete the file here
            Log.e("-->", "Success, file Deleted :" + file_path);
        } else {
            Log.e("-->", "file not Deleted :" + file_path);
        }
}
```

`exists()` will check if it is exist or not so, no need for extra condition.

It's better to add the codes inside `try-catch` in order to catch all situations in future. (Don't have permission or any errors)

Comment: Thanks for answering, it still does not work .exists() return TRUE but .delete() still not executing

Comment: Use try-catch to see what’s the issue. Make sure about the file name. Perhaps, copy pasting the file’s name in the code?

Comment: When debugging Try-Catch does not throw any exception I think this is because the method responds with a boolean. Also try copy pasting the file worse yet it does not work

Comment: Im facing this issue.Delete function returns false and doesnt throw exception.Did you solve this problem?